# d3 brush: not a rectangle but a circle?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geometry, brush, drawellipse

We wish to use a d3 brush to select neighobrs in a scatter plot.   For this, a circle is more natural than a rectangle.  I imagine a sequence of actions:

1) set the circle's center with a mouse click

2) adjust the radius with mouse motion, the x & y components of the current mouse position perhaps even implying an ellipse

In all the examples my web search finds, the brushed region is a rectangle.

Any advice, or working examples?

Thanks!

- Puaul

Comment: The brush behaviour as implemented in D3 only supports rectangles.

Comment: Thanks, Lars.   Would my best fallback position be to provide circle or ellipse drawing on top of the scatter plot? -- which, when complete, I interrogate for its coordinates?  Then find which scatter plot points intersect the new circle?

Comment: Yes, that's basically what you would have to do.

Comment: thanks, Lars!  Your answer gets me working on the right problem...

Comment: No, brush in d3 can have different shapes.

Comment: Hi VividD.   Can you point us to an example, or documentation?  I would be very grateful!

Comment: Hi Paul, I know this is an old topic but did you finally succeed in using a circular brush?